# Time complexity : how to calculate logkn using definition?

Tags: time-complexity

I have a method :

```
while (i<k) {
  i = i * k
}
```

I know it’s `O(logkn)` time complexity (and easy to demonstrate by examples), but I don’t find how we actually get this using the definition of `O(g(n))`:

> We say `f(n)` has time complexity `O(g(n))` if there exists constant `c > 0, n0 >=1` that `f(n) <= c*g(n)`.

In our case, how do we find `g(n) = logkn` ?